# How do I eliminate all the parenthesis in a txt files?

Tags: python, list, parentheses

I have a txt file, single COLUMN, taken from excel, of the following type:

AMANDA (LOUDLY SPEAKING)
JEFF
STEVEN (TEASINGLY)
AMANDA
DOC BRIAN GREEN

As output I want:

AMANDA
JEFF
STEVEN
AMANDA
DOC BRIAN GREEN

I tried with a for cycle on all the column and then:

```
            if (str[i] == '('):  
                return str.split('(')
```

but it's clearly not working. 
Do you have any possible solution? I would then need an output file as my original txt, so with each name for each line in a single column.

Thanks everyone!
(I am using PyCharm 3.2)

Comment: [str.replace(')','').replace('(','')](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.replace)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use regex in this situation. `\w` will replace letters, the `*` will select 0 or more.  Then we check that it is between parenthesis.

```
import re
fi = "AMANDA (LOUDLY) JEFF STEVEN (TEASINGLY) AMANDA"
with open("mytext.txt","r") as fi, open("out.txt", "w") as fo:
    for line in fi:
        fo.write(re.sub("\(.*?\)", "", line))
```

Comment: f = open("mytext.txt","r")
         file = f.readlines()
and then 
         print re.sub("\(\w*\)", "", fi)

Because I have thousands lines, by copying and pasting it would take some times.

Comment: This may work on this case but will not work with strings that has non-word characters like: (LOUDLY **!**) or even strings that have empty spaces like (STACK OVERFLOW)

Comment: I'm checking it!
what about the output file? because I would need a txt file again as the initial

Comment: Updated code with an output file.  If you could mark as solution, it would help a lot.

Comment: Is it the fi = "AMANDA...." necessary?
Also, the output file I need has to be in the same form as the input, so each name on a different line, making 1 column.

Comment: Okay, I answered the question as it was asked.  I am having a hard time understanding the follow up questions.  I think you have a great starting point.  You should check out my profile and hit me up on discord.

Answer (score 0):

You can split the string into a list using a regular expression that matches everything in parentheses or a full word, remove all elements from the list which contain parentheses and then join the list to a string again. The advantage is that there will be no double spaces in the result string where a word in parantheses was removed.

```
import re
text = "AMANDA (LOUDLY SPEAKING) JEFF STEVEN (TEASINGLY) AMANDA DOC BRIAN GREEN"
words = re.findall("\(.*?\)|[^\s]+",text)
print " ".join([x for x in words if "(" not in x])
```

Comment: the problem I would have is in the case of a double space (made accidentally) or composite names (like MR ROSS, DOC ROB GREEN) 
What if I use the "( " as separator?

Comment: This solution doesn't work if the strings in parentheses contain spaces as it relies on the space as a separator. If this is a requirement, splitting using a regular expression `re.findall("\(.*?\)|[^\s]+",text)` is the better choice.

Comment: Updated answer so that it works with spaces in parentheses.